# Microsoft Edge のSelenium用のWeb Driverについて

Tags: java, selenium

Windows 10 Anniversary Update(14393)後のMicrosoft Edgeに対応するSelenium用のWeb Driverを以下よりダウンロードしました。

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/

本来ダウンロードセンター（https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48212）からダウンロードするべきですが、左記のダウンロードリンクにあるWeb DriverではAnniversary Updateに対応しておりませんでした。

そこで問題が発生しているのが、背景色の取得に使用する「getCssValue("back-ground")」の戻り値が「rdb(0,0,0)」となっており、他のWebDriverで取得される「rgba(0,0,0,0)」と不合致になっています。

同一事象が発生されている方はおりませんでしょうか？
また、本来、最新のWeb Driverはどこからダウンロードするべきでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> また、本来、最新のWeb Driverはどこからダウンロードするべきでしょうか？

今はダウンロードセンターよりは https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/ からダウンロードする方が正しいと思います。
（Microsoftとしても扱いがいろいろと過渡期かもしれませんので、近い将来にはまた変わるかもしれません）

> そこで問題が発生しているのが、背景色の取得に使用する「getCssValue("back-ground")」の戻り値が「rdb(0,0,0)」となっており、他のWebDriverで取得される「rgba(0,0,0,0)」と不合致になっています。

試してみたところ、MicrosoftWebDriverが、というよりは、
Edgeの仕様で色空間は統一されておらず
指定により要素ごとにRGB色空間とRGBA色空間を切り替えられるようです。

元の色指定が #ff0000 のようなRGBカラーコードだと
rgb(255, 0, 0) のようにRGB色空間として返ってきますが、
元の色指定が rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.9) のようなRGBA指定だと
rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.9) とRGBA色空間で返ってきます。